# How to use a function of nodejs to use in a button in html for use joohny five?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, johnny-five

I create a server using nodejs with express

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//add the router
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/View'));
//Store all HTML files in view folder.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Script'));
//Store all JS and CSS in Scripts folder.
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
```

And use html with javascript.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <script type="text" src="./server.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <body>
        <h1>Automatico</h1>
        <button onclick="autohabilitar();">Habilitar</button>
        <button onclick="autodeshabilitar();">deshabilitar</button>
        <br>
        <h1>Foco-1</h1>
        <button onclick="f1habilitar();" id="f1h">Habilitar</button>
        <button onclick="f1deshabilitar();"id="f1d">deshabilitar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
   document.getElementById("f1h").disabled=true;
   document.getElementById("f1d").disabled=true;
}

function autodeshabilitar(){
    document.getElementById("f1h").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("f1d").disabled=false;
}

function f1habilitar(){
    document.getElementById("f1h").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("f1d").disabled=false;
}

function f1deshabilitar(){
    document.getElementById("f1d").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("f1h").disabled=false;
}
```

I need the function

```
function apagarf1(){
  led1.off();
}
```

located in **server.js** for use in onclick of the button...
I tried export the function, import the script in the html, use johnny-five in another script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not super familiar with Johnny 5. But I do know you can’t access node.js specific stuff from the browser.

Your best bet will be to set up a basic api endpoint in express that you call from your front end code. When that endpoint gets hit you can trigger your nodejs function to turn the led off.

In your server file add this:

```
app.get('/led-off', (req, res) => {

  apagarf1()

  return res.send('LED off');

});
```

On your front end make a fetch() call to that endpoint and that should work.